# Why does MongoLab not recommend using their REST API?

Tags: mongodb, rest, mlab

From the [MongoLab's documentation](http://docs.mongolab.com/connecting/#rest-api), they recommend:

> *MongoLab databases can be accessed by your application code in two ways.*
>
> *The first method - the one we strongly recommend - is to connect using one of the MongoDB drivers (as described above). You do not need
>   to use our API if you use the driver.*
>
> *The second method, which you should use only if you cannot connect via one of the MongoDB drivers, is via MongoLab’s RESTful data API.*

Why do they recommend using the driver rather than their REST API? One reason I can think of is portability across different MongoDB providers. Are there any other reasons? Wouldn't it be more beneficial for MongoLab to "vendor lock-in" customers with their API?

Comment: Dunno why don't you ask them?

Comment: If not done correctly, you'll give someone complete access to your databases. The only security is an API key -- and then you can do **anything** with the account databases. Why would you want to use it? The drivers should always perform better than the equivalent REST api.

Comment: There is a warning on MongoLab's [REST API](http://docs.mongolab.com/restapi/) page which is similar to @WiredPrairie's caution: `This API key will give full access to all data within the databases belonging to your MongoLab account. If you do not have it secured on an app server, someone can gain access to it and your data.`.

Answer (score 4):

The points that @WiredPrairie and @Stennie brought up around security are correct. *When you use our REST API, you expose your API key to the client. Currently, anyone with the API key can modify your database. As a result, we only recommend using the REST API with public data, e.g. all the locations for taco trucks in the country.

By writing your own app tier, you can keep credentials to your database from being exposed to the client.

If you have any more questions, email us at support@mongolab.com. Happy to help!

-Chris@MongoLab

p.s. thanks @WiredPrairie and @Stennie